# What does the Cosmic Power boost do?

Tags: robot-unicorn-attack-2

Robot Unicorn Attack 2 just had some level restrictions removed and I noticed a whole bunch of new stuff everywhere. Among them "Cosmic Power", a mysterious boost that's locked to me.

[image: Cosmic Power - Get this Boost if you join Team Rainbow today!]

I don't actually use boosts because muh coins, but I'm still curious because of the outrageous price it demands (669 coins *and* running for Team Losing Losers).

Anyone know what exactly it does? I don't really want to pay a double traitor fee to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched sides in order to find out...

[image]

Comment: Well. Thanks for the noble sacrifice of all your coins, it looks like. That boost doesn't seem worthwhile, especially since you'd be giving up daily coin prizes.

Comment: @lunboks It was free for me to swap but I've been playing to build up coins to jump back to inferno...these rainbows are creepy...

Comment: I didn't notice any difference between having the boost and not, except for the dash animation changes when you use it during flying. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh and BTW I'm team inferno. We LOST yesterday and to the losers go the 469 cost boost.

Comment: @Dan You may want to ask that in a separate question.

Comment: This screenshot doesn't show "what exactly it does". Even without the powerup, you can dash to smash through obstacles, whether flying or not. I have used this powerup and I didn't observe any change.

Comment: @hypehuman dude, this answer is 4 years old. I'm sorry, but you're nit-picking over the fact that I didnt have a screen recorder..

Comment: @ColeBusby I appreciate the screenshot, as it does hint generally at what some possible answers might be. I'm just pointing out that it doesn't fully answer the question. A full answer would not have to be a recording; it could be a description of how the unicorn behaves differently with and without the powerup.

Answer (score -1):

I've heard what it does is allow you to infinitely dash when flying.
Because, after you hit your max air jumps you can dash, then jump 2x and then you run out of dashes.